# Delayed resize on timer - responsive accordion / faq right or bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, timer

I am playing with a mobile first, responsive FAQ that uses an accordion-like structure - showing info in a DL to the right if big enough or underneath if too big.

http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/xJrts?editors=001

Unfortunately I cannot get the delayed timer on resize to work. Open the pen above with the console open and you will see the resize firing lots and lots, where I thought the code below would force it to fire once a second:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
  $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(MiniFAQ.resize(), 1000));
});
```

What have I done wrong?

Any other comments on the pen welcome. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to put your `setTimeout` code in a function to achieve the results you are looking for, like this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
  $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {MiniFAQ.resize();}, 1000));
});
```

Comment: Arghh! How did I miss that. Thank you Jem, that fixed it.